# C++ structs exercise

Tags: c++, visual-c++, struct

I'm trying to complete a structs exercise;

> 1. a.  You will define and declare struct data with the following 3 hypothetical student information in this course. Assume Lab score is 70% and Test score is 30% of the total grades.
>
> ```
> First name (string)   :   John            Alisa           Mike    
> Last name (string)    :   White           Brown           Green
> Course Grade (char)   :   0 (to be calculated)    “           “
> Test score (int)      :   88          90          75
> Lab score (int)       :   70          64          97
> ```
>
> b.    Perform the following tasks:
>
> - Initialize/declare each student in struct data type. Notice the IntelliSense feature of MVS.
> - Calculate Course grade with a function call (i.e. getGrade). This could be a void function pass-by-reference or appropriate char function to return course grade. Inputs will be the test score and the labs score. The percentages (30% and 70%) could be defined as global double constants. Use step-by-step incremental approach to develop your code.
> - Display the student information back to the user. Try to use a function call to print this output (See page 620). And ask me for some ideas about how to proceed.  A sample output might be:
>
> ```
> John    White   Grade is: C     Test Score is: 88       Lab Score is: 70
> Alisa   Brown   Grade is: C     Test Score is: 90       Lab Score is: 64
> Mike    Green   Grade is: A     Test Score is: 75       Lab Score is: 97
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Here's what I have put together so far and am stuck- Not sure why I'm not getting the desired output. (any help would be greatly appreciated!):

```
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double testweight = 0.30;
const double labweight = 0.70;
char getGrade(int testScore, int labScore) {
    if ((testweight * testScore) + (labweight * labScore) >= 90)
        return 'A';
    else if ((testweight * testScore) + (labweight * labScore) >= 80)
        return 'B';
    else if ((testweight * testScore) + (labweight * labScore) >= 70)
        return 'C';
    else if ((testweight * testScore) + (labweight * labScore) >= 60)
        return 'D';
    else return 'F';
}


struct studentType
{
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int testScore;
    int labScore;
    char grade;

};


void printstudent(studentType student)
{
    cout << student.studentFName << " " << student.studentLName
        << "" << student.testScore
        << "" << student.labScore
        << "" << student.grade << endl;
}
int main()
{

    studentType student1;
    studentType student2;
    studentType student3;

    student1.studentFName = "John";
    student1.studentLName = "White";
    student1.testScore = 88;
    student1.labScore = 70;
    student1.grade = getGrade(student1.testScore, student1.labScore);

    student2.studentFName = "Alisa";
    student2.studentLName = "Brown";
    student2.testScore = 90;
    student2.labScore = 64;
    student2.grade = getGrade(student2.testScore, student2.labScore);

    student3.studentFName = "Mike";
    student3.studentLName = "Green";
    student3.testScore = 75;
    student3.labScore = 97;
    student3.grade = getGrade(student3.testScore, student3.labScore);

    void printstudent(studentType student);
}
```

Comment: What is your question, the error you have...? Read [ask]

Comment: It this is printing, it is not the code you are running. The last line is a function declaration, not a call.

Comment: `void printstudent(studentType student);` -- In the `main` function you have, what does that line do?

Comment: the printstudent function is being invoked wrong. Should be `printstudent(student1); printstudent(student2);` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This..

```
void printstudent(studentType student);
```

is not how you call a function (it is a function declaration).

After replacing that line with

```
printStudent(student3);
// ^^ name of the function to call
//           ^^ parameter(s) passed to the function
```

I get the following output:

```
Mike Green7597A
```

You probably want to add some blanks and print also the other students. I suggest you to study `std::vector` and loops to make your code easier.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your code is a function declaration. This should be function call. Replace it with one or all lines from code below:

```
printstudent(student1);
printstudent(student2);
printstudent(student3);
```

For function call you need function_name, parenthesis in which you put argument and semicolon at the end.

```
function_name(argument);
```